# ajax call not posting json data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax

Iam trying to send some JSON data to the server using jquery ajax call. It doesn't seem like the data is posting as when i try to parse it in the code-behind file it throws errors. Searched around but the answers didn't help solve my problem. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Default2.aspx',
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //data: "'"+batchtable+"'",
        data: JSON.stringify({"a":"1", "b": "2"}),
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var jsonString = String.Empty;
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        RootObject userinput = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonString);

    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

The error message I get is:

```
Invalid JSON primitive: __VIEWSTATE.
```

Answer (score 2):

for ajax call don't call from server side event.you need to call from javascript/jquery.

you need to define a serverside webmethod and you can call that method from the jquery/javascript. here is a demo. works fine. might be helpful for you.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#btnResult").click(function () {
             var name = $("#txtNameTextBox").val();
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
                 data: "{name:'" + name + "'}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {
                     //alert(data.d);
                     $("#Result").text(data.d);

                     var val = data.d;
                     val = val.split("~");
                     var name = val[0];
                     var time = val[1];
                     var date = val[2];
                     var tempdate = date.split(":");
                     var finaldate = tempdate[1];
                     $("#txtDateToDisplay").val(finaldate);
                     $("#txtDateToDisplay2").val(finaldate);
                 },
                 error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }
             });
         });

     });
 </script>
```

here is HTML

```
<h2>
    Call Server side Function From JaxaScript AJAX Call ASP.NET!
</h2>
<br />
<br />
<div>
  Name  : <input type="text" id="txtNameTextBox" /><br/><br/>
  Date  : <input type="text" id="txtDateToDisplay" /><br/><br/>
  Date  : <input type="text" id="txtDateToDisplay2" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <p id="Result">Message : </p>
 <input type="button" id="btnResult" value="Click here for the time"/>
</div>
```

And here your server side code

```
     /// <summary>
    /// ===========================================
    /// This is the WebMethod where ajax call happens.
    //=============================================
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">the data sent from ajax call 
    /// - here a string only(name of a user)</param>
    /// <returns>a string with json format</returns>

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string GetDate(string name)
    {
        if (name == "")
        {
            return "No Parcel Available";
        }
        else
        {
            name = "Name : " + name + "~" +
                    "Current Time : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
                    + "~" + "Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        }

       return name;
    }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for the response. The issue turned out to be totally unrelated (jquery library issues). My mistake for not verifying that first..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript/jQuery to call a server-side endpoint. ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods provide web methods that are hosted inside of a page, but are `static` and are not part of the page instance, so you can call them asynchronously via your client-side script, like this:

Markup:

```
<div id="Results"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YourPage.aspx/GetGreeting",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            // Put greeting into DIV
            $('#Results').text(result.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetGreeting()
{
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

Note: The above example uses the client (via jQuery) to ask the server for a greeting (`string`), which is JSON-encoded automatically by the ASP.NET AJAX Page Method. The `result` is then processed by the `success` handler of the jQuery `.ajax()` function and the actual `string` value is pulled out of the `.d` reference in the returned `JSON` object.

Comment: thanks for the response. The issue turned out to be totally unrelated (jquery library issues). My mistake for not verifying that first..